# Sony WH-1000XM3 BT headphones stops working after some time

Tags: audio, opensuse, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I'm using Sony WH-1000XM3 bluetooth headphones with my openSUSE 15.2 with kernel 5.8. Everything works fine most of the time, but sometimes (few minutes to 1 hour after connecting headphones) sound just stops working. I have to disconnect and reconnect headphones to get sound working again. When that error occurs I can see following logs in journalctl:

```
[ 9173.598359] Bluetooth: hci0: Received unexpected HCI Event 00000000
[ 9173.598363] Bluetooth: hci0: Received unexpected HCI Event 00000000
[ 9173.598364] Bluetooth: hci0: Received unexpected HCI Event 00000000
[ 9173.622376] Bluetooth: hci0: Received unexpected HCI Event 00000000
```

and sometimes after disconnecting headphones also this:

```
[ 9186.124245] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x041f tx timeout
```

I've searched for similar problems, but I haven't found any results, except part of linux sources: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/bluetooth/hci_event.c#L6025 which was added there half year ago: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/08bb4da90150e2a225f35e0f642cdc463958d696

That issue is very annoying especially during online meetings, so I'm trying to fix it somehow. So far I've compiled bluez 5.54 and added more codecs (https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt), but it hasn't changed anything. I've also tried disabling powersaving for bluetooth module using following kernel params:

```
btusb.enable_autosuspend=n usbcore.autosuspend=-1 usbcore.autosuspend_delay_ms=-1
```

but that also didn't fix that issue.

My bluetooth adapter:

```
8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
```

Comment: If you're also using Wifi, there could be interactions between wifi and bluetooth (which is still a bug). I got this issue on an intel dual wifi/bluetooth chipset. You could try not using Wifi or limiting Wifi to the 5Ghz band if available (afaik bluetooth operates only in 2.4Ghz) and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been having this issue for a while. Finally got time to look into it. Came across your question. Also came across a similar question with an [answer](https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg434503.html). Testing them. So far no issue. Essentially, the solution involves updating two firmware files in `/lib/firmware/intel`.

**Approach 1 - Use Focal Intel firmware files:**

[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/plain/intel/ibt-20-1-3.ddc?h=focal](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/plain/intel/ibt-20-1-3.ddc?h=focal)
[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/plain/intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi?h=focal](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/plain/intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi?h=focal)

```
$ cd  /lib/firmware/intel/
$ sudo cp ibt-20-1-3.ddc ibt-20-1-3.ddc.bak
$ sudo cp ibt-20-1-3.sfi ibt-20-1-3.sfi.bak
$ sudo mv ~/Downloads/ibt-20-1-3.ddc ibt-20-1-3.ddc
$ sudo mv ~/Downloads/ibt-20-1-3.sfi ibt-20-1-3.sfi
```

**Approach 2 - Use upstream linux-firmware:**

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/intel/ibt-20-1-3.ddc
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi

Run the same commands above to make the change.